# How to save one API response to WooCommerce order meta data

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order, api, json

Have one custom checkout field email type that validates if the email exists or not in a remote server. I sent JSON data to the remote server with this field.

If email exists JSON response typically:

```
{
    "success": "ok",
    "responseCode": "200",
    "token": "I0b6uSNelqwGv+sCHpTV6LYI08hxcwoBIMVHh5mKVx+fkRFscUKbvUBF8+rl0vACgMImcffCzLsf571KLQVkSYcvdUfdwsu8mrBQ8mBw5J1LZtFs/7PwXerjNS2HjBAB0tc+RqZhYJ9Ne1efn7fq7Df4kAQ+QO7CjBKUwp8k7pFYslLMcWuxfb+KKsotZP82gkk5oKZEeh30a6K2I7dAxRj+B3RqyqND/uRO1uqQ1IA="
}
```

Where "token" value changes per request.

I want to save the token how metadata inside the order, after check what response code = 200

Using `$order->update_meta_data( 'received_token_key', $token );` not work alone, I know what I have one big error, but I can't find this one.

Maybe using another WooCommerce hook?
Maybe using wc_session?
Maybe save to another place and recall it?

I need what before checkout occurs, the email from custom field to be validated,  if not, `wc_add_notice($response_message, 'error');` will be triggered.

```
         // start here
   add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', (custom_checkout_field_process_valid' );

   function custom_checkout_field_process_valid($order_id) {

        $url = 'https://remoteserver.com/api/checking-email-registered-user.json';
        $body = array("email"=>($_POST['email_pasajero']),); //from custom field
        $response2 = wp_remote_post( $url, 
            array(
                'headers'   => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
                'method'    => 'POST',
                'timeout' => 75,                    
                'body'      => json_encode($body),));

         // check and use the response
$response_code       = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response2 );
$response_message = wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $response2 );
$bodyarray = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response2 ));
$token = $bodyarray["token"]; 

    if ($response_code == 200)  {
        // I want to save $token or its value, in this step, how metadata for later use
       // maybe directly from the response?
        // $order->update_meta_data( 'token_received_key', $token ); not work
    }

            else {
         wc_add_notice($response_message, 'error');
                return $response_code ;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close.

`$order->update_meta_data()` will update the meta value inside the `$order` object, but it will not store the change in the database. To save changes to a [WooCommerce CRUD object](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/developing-using-woocommerce-crud-objects/) you need to run the `save()` method:

```
if ( $response_code == 200 )  {
    $order->update_meta_data( 'token_received_key', $token );
    $order->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @jacob, but this does not work, give me internal server error how exception. when placing the order. When i set this how test sample: ```if ($response_code == 200) { wc_add_notice( $token , 'error' );} ```the error message show the token, any idea?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: show the message x Internal server error after place the order

Comment: didn't work for me either